# How to correctly use group by for getting the record with the closest time for each rec_id

Tags: group-by, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

**Background**

I have a table `records` which stores `rec_id`, `rec_time` and `rec_value`. A record is stored for each `rec_id` only when its `rec_value` changes. I would like to query the value for a bunch of `rec_id`s at a given time.

For a single `rec_id` this query works perfectly fine to query its value at `rec_time` 590:

```
SELECT rec_time,rec_value 
FROM records 
WHERE rec_id = 4 AND rec_time <= 590 
ORDER BY time DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

I use `rec_time <= 590` as the latest value can be set at any instance at or before `590`.

**PROBLEM**

I would like to extend this to work for multiple `rec_id`s in a single query.

```
SELECT rec_id,rec_time,rec_value 
FROM records 
WHERE rec_id IN (4,9,21,565,951,93,6,15,64) 
AND rec_time <= 590 
GROUP BY rec_id 
ORDER BY time DESC, rec_id ASC;
```

The query above seems to work but I have noticed that I get inconsistent results and I figured that I'm not using `GROUP BY` correctly.

I have tried a few solutions found in slightly different questions here, but I haven't found any solution which gives consistent results yet.

Can this be solved with `GROUP BY` or should I use nested queries. If so, how? I gave a shot at using `JOIN` but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Do you need one record per different `code_id` and per different `rec_id`? You're grouping but not applying grouping or functions to the selected results. Adding a table and some sample data + expected result could help getting to an answer faster.

Comment: Hi, let me edit the question. I was converting my table to more meaningful names and hastily made some mistakes. code_id = rec_id. Sorry about that!
I need 1 record for each rec_id which gives me the rec_value for a given rec_time.

Comment: No problem! I think that you need to either add rec_time,rec_value to the group by, or apply a function to it like MAX() or MIN()

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT rec_id, 
                     rec_time, 
                     FIRST_VALUE(rec_value) OVER (PARTITION BY rec_id ORDER BY rec_time DESC) rec_value
              FROM records 
              WHERE rec_id IN (4,9,21,565,951,93,6,15,64) 
              AND rec_time <= 590 )
SELECT rec_id, MAX(rec_time) rec_time, rec_value
FROM cte 
GROUP BY rec_id /* , rec_value */ ;
```

or ever

```
SELECT DISTINCT rec_id, 
                MAX(rec_time) OVER (PARTITION BY rec_id) rec_time, 
                FIRST_VALUE(rec_value) OVER (PARTITION BY rec_id ORDER BY rec_time DESC) rec_value
FROM records 
WHERE rec_id IN (4,9,21,565,951,93,6,15,64) 
AND rec_time <= 590;
```

Comment: Hi do you know if this works for SQLite? I am getting some error at '('. I will look into it and update here if it works or not. Thanks

Comment: *Hi do you know if this works for SQLite?* Check it using some online fiddle (create tables, insert sample data, then test the queries). On https://dbfiddle.uk/, for example...

Comment: What I meant to ask was if you are aware about SQLite supporting PARTITION and CTE, terms which I hadn't come across before. Seems like PARTITION isn't supported but `WITH` is supported. I'll try to get that working and update here. Thanks

Comment: @srik "Built-in window functions honor any PARTITION BY clause in the same way as aggregate window functions - each selected row is assigned to a partition and each partition is processed separately." [SQLite - Window functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#biwinfunc). Maybe SQLite may use separate WINDOW clause only - check, and, if true, edit.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'll look into it.